# How to control vertical space with .pack in Tkinter/Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, position

I need to centralize my labels (dinamically) but I want to control its position in y axis, so I've tried pack. The problem is: .pack() doesn't allow me to add a vertical space >only< above the label, just bellow AND above.

I've tried this code:

```
l1 = Label(janela,text="Testando1",bg='green')
l1.pack(ipady=20)

l2 = Label(janela,text="Testando2")
l2.pack()
```

And get this:

[image]

Look that `ipady` adds some spaces above and bellow the label, and I need to add spaces only above.

I've tried to read the documentation but I didn't find anything useful for this problem.

I want something like that:

[image]

It doesn't count because I jerry-rigged with .place() to get this result.

Comment: I want them exactly in the center, but I want to control vertical space. I need just to add a vertical space above the label, not bellow

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted what you were looking for, `pady = (40,0)` will add 40 above and 0 below.

Comment: Yes, is this! Would you post your answer?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I'm gonna close this question

Comment: Seemed more appropriate to just mark it duplicate, I just don't like to leave people hanging.

Comment: set `pady = (40, 0)` in method `pack` doesn't get output as request. Maybe option `anchor='s'` when label initialize and `ipady = 10` in method `pack` for it.